# How do I get the user to input an int rather than a float?

Tags: python, floating-point, int

I'm writing a program that takes in a value from the user, in the console, and I'm casting it to an `int` like so:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

I need my program to work with `ints` only. This works to convert an actual int entered into the console to an int I can use in the program, but if the user enters a float, like 3.1, then it doesn't cast to an int by truncating or rounding up for example.

How do I get the user to input an int rather than a float? Or how do I convert a floating point input to an int?

Comment: Hi please set `num = int(round(float(input("Enter a number: ")),0))` and see. You will definitely get the desired output. I hope it helps!!!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a try catch block to ensure they only give you an `int`:

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        #do something with num and then break out of the while loop with break
    except ValueError:
        print("That was not a number, please do not use decimals!")
```

When ValueError (when it fails to convert to int) is excepted it goes back to asking for a number which once you get your number you can do things with said number or break out of the loop then and use num elsewhere.

Comment: You missed a `break`, TreatyBreaker.

Comment: On purpose, take a look at the comment in there, you don't *necessarily* need to break out then, you can do logic right in that loop and then break when you're done; it entirely depends on the need of the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `try` `except` to test if a user input is a whole number. Example code:

```
while True:
    try:
        value=int(input("Type a number:"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("This is not a whole number.")
```

This code will loop back to the start if a user inputs something that is not an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

So int() of a string like "3.1" doesnt work of course. But you can cast the input to a float and then to int:

```
num = int(float(input("Enter a number: ")))
```

It will always round down. If you want it to round up if >= .5:

```
num = float(input("Enter a number: "))
num = round(num, 0)
num = int(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use eval python built-in function. 
`num = int(eval(input("Enter a number: ")))`. 
For converting string into python code and evaluating mathimatical expressions, eval function is mostly used. For example, `eval("2 + 3")` will give you 5. However, if you write `"2 + 3"`, then u will get only `'2 + 3'` as string value.

Comment: But the `eval` is dangerous to use esp. with inputs. This shouldn't be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
num = int(float(input("Enter number: ")))
```

and the float will be rounded to int.
You can also add a try...except method to give error to user if the number cannot be converted for any reason:

```py
while True:
    try:
        num = int(float(input("Enter number: ")))
        print(num)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("This is not a whole number")
```

Answer (score -1):

use `abs()` it returns the absolute value of the given number

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num = abs(num). Didn't vote you down btw.